# How can I check if my computer has AES-NI support?

Tags: encryption, cpu

I've heard that disk encryption works reasonably faster when CPU supports AES-NI. How can I check if my CPU supports it? Does the Ubuntus default encryption (`dm-crypt`) use it by default or do I have to enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep aes /proc/cpuinfo
```

if there is output that starts with `flags` and there is something like `aes` your system supports it.

You can also check [this list](http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced/?AESTech=true) from intel (268 boards support it).